# Can I use before in between tests as shown in following code?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I want to compute some values before some tests. what is the best way to do that? To use "before" or call functions?

```
// Way 1
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe("a test", function() {
    var val1, val2;
    before(function() {
        val1 = computeVal1();
    });

    it("should return hi1", function() {
        expect(val1).to.equal('hi1');
    });

    before(function() {
        val2 = computeVal2();
    });

    it("should return hi2", function() {
        expect(val2).to.equal('hi2');
    });
});
```

Is the above way is better or the below way is better?

```
// Way 2
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe("a test", function() {
    var val1, val2;
    val1 = computeVal1();

    it("should return hi1", function() {
        expect(val1).to.equal('hi1');
    });


    val2 = computeVal2();

    it("should return hi2", function() {
        expect(val2).to.equal('hi2');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It really makes no difference in this case because ultimately in the second example `computeVal1()` will run before the tests do. However, given this is exactly what the `before` / `beforeEach` hooks were designed for, I would be inclined to stay consistent with the framework and use them.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [mocha documentation](http://mochajs.org/):

```
describe('hooks', function() {
  before(function() {
    // runs before all tests in this block
  })
  after(function(){
    // runs after all tests in this block
  })
  beforeEach(function(){
    // runs before each test in this block
  })
  afterEach(function(){
    // runs after each test in this block
  })
  // test cases
})
```

So, there is not much difference in using `before` or calling functions directly under the `describe`.  In your second example, `val2`'s value won't be available to the first test, but in the first example, `val2`'s value will be.

However, it is better practice IMO, to use `beforeEach`.  This way state from one test does not affect another test.

Answer (score 0):

Using the hooks (`before` and `beforeEach`) to initialize the data that your test uses is usually the best thing to do. Consider this:

1. In your 2nd snippet, if `computeVal1` or `computeVal2` fail, then Mocha won't run any test whatsoever. In the 1st snippet, Mocha may run some tests before it tries to call them and they fail. If you have many test files that Mocha loads, **it may matter to you that Mocha runs as many test as it can before a failure occurs.**
2. In your 2nd snippet, Mocha will **almost always** run `computeVal1` and `computeVal2` even if they are not needed. **If they are computationally costly, you'll pay this cost every time.** If you run `mocha --grep=foo` so that it does not select any of your tests, both functions *will* be called.

   In your first snippet, Mocha will run them only if they are needed. If you run `mocha --grep=foo`, Mocha won't call your functions.

   In  your 2nd snippet, even using `describe.skip` for your `describe` call won't make Mocha skip calling the functions.